# Safari WebDriver setTimeout using protractor exiting

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I have done a lot of unit tests using Karma, but my office would like to have some integration tests, especially testing cross browser capabilities. For this, it seemed Protractor was my best option, and I have started get get some basic dashboard tests going, but am stuck with safari.

**My Config:**

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    specs: ['scenarios/*Scenario.js'],

    framework: 'jasmine',

    baseUrl: 'https://www-dev.remeeting.com/',

    multiCapabilities: [{
        browserName: 'firefox'
    }, {
       browserName: 'chrome'
    }, {
       browserName: 'safari'
    }],

    onPrepare: function() {
        browser.driver.get('https://www-dev.remeeting.com/');

        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('email')).sendKeys('adam+test@mod9.com');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('abc123');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('submit_btn')).click();

        // Login takes some time, so wait until it's done.
        // For the test app's login, we know it's done when it redirects to
        // app/#/d.
        return browser.driver.wait(function() {
            return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
                return /app\/#\/d/.test(url);
            });
        }, 10000);
    }
};
```

**My only spec**

```
describe('Dashboard', function() {
    it('should login to the dashboard', function() {
        expect(element(by.css('.dashboard')).getText()).toMatch(/Upload Meeting/);
        expect(element(by.id('refreshButton')));
        expect(element(by.css('.dashboard div.btn-group')))
    });
});
```

**And the error**

```
[safari #21] PID: 79079
[safari #21] Specs: /Users/adam/git/mrp-  www/e2e/scenarios/dashboardScenario.js
[safari #21]
[safari #21] Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[safari #21] ERROR - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
[safari #21] Unknown command: setTimeout (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
...
[safari #21] Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
[safari #21] Capabilities [{browserName=safari, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, version=9.1, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, platform=MAC, secureSsl=true}]
[safari #21] Session ID: null

[launcher] Runner process exited unexpectedly with error code: 1
[launcher] 2 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
```

Anybody know how to configure protractor for safari?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I did to successfully set up Safari + Protractor:

- made sure I have the latest Safari (9.1 at the moment)
- downloaded the latest Safari driver from [this page](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), opened the Safari extensions preferences and dragged and dropped the `SafariDriver.safariextz` file into the extension list:

[image]

- upgraded `protractor` to the latest version (3.2.2 at the moment)

---

Note that, as an alternative, you can always run Safari remotely on [`BrowserStack`](http://browserstack.com/) or [`SauceLabs`](https://saucelabs.com/).

---

See also the [list of Safari+Protractor issues](https://github.com/angular/protractor/labels/browser%3A%20safari).